# dgram NodeJS sending datagram to specific IP in LAN

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, udp, dgrams

## Problem:

I can't figure out how to correctly use `Node.js` and `dgram` to send a UDP packet to a specific IP address within the same LAN (not behind a NAT)

---

## Attempted Solution

I found [Send Broadcast datagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177423/send-broadcast-datagram) showcasing how to use `dgram` with `Node.js` to send out UDP broadcasts.

`server.js`

```js
var PORT = 6024;
var BROADCAST_ADDR = "192.168.0.255"; // substitute here
var dgram = require('dgram');
var server = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

server.bind(function() {
    server.setBroadcast(true);
    setInterval(broadcastNew, 3000);
});

function broadcastNew() {
    var message = Buffer.from("Broadcast message!");
    server.send(message, 0, message.length, PORT, BROADCAST_ADDR, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("Sent '" + message + "'");
    });
}
```

`client.js`

```js
var PORT = 6024;
var dgram = require('dgram');
var client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

client.on('listening', function () {
    var address = client.address();
    console.log('UDP Client listening on ' + address.address + ":" + address.port);
    client.setBroadcast(true);
});

client.on('message', function (message, rinfo) {
    console.log('Message from: ' + rinfo.address + ':' + rinfo.port +' - ' + message);
});

client.bind(PORT);
```

This appears to work correctly as I can confirm that the packets are being sent by using [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) with a display filter of `udp.port==6024`.

I then tried to do `BROADCAST_ADDR` = `192.168.0.26`. `server.js` is run on computer 1 with `192.168.0.25` and `client.js` is run on computer 2 with `192.168.0.26`. `server.js` does not show any errors, but both wireshark and `client.js` doesn't detect anything `server.js` is sending out.

I then tried to do `BROADCAST_ADDR` = `192.168.0.25` (basically sending to own IP address), and ran the 2 files on the same computer. `client.js` successfully receives the messages from `server.js`, but wireshark doesn't detect anything, which is very confusing to me.

---

I also tried to change `server.js` to

```js
var PORT = 6024;
var BROADCAST_ADDR = "192.168.0.25";
var dgram = require('dgram');
var server = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

server.bind(function() {
    //server.setBroadcast(true);
    server.connect(PORT, BROADCAST_ADDR);
    setInterval(broadcastNew, 3000);
});

function broadcastNew() {
    var message = Buffer.from("Broadcast message!");
    server.send(message, 0, message.length, /*PORT, BROADCAST_ADDR,*/ function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("Sent '" + message + "'");
    });
}
```

but this doesn't actually change the behaviour

---

Another similar question is [How to send a UDP packet via dgram in Nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53540687/how-to-send-a-udp-packet-via-dgram-in-nodejs)
If I take this question's accepted solution code and edit it into

```js
var dgram = require('dgram');

var client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

client.send('Hello World!',0, 12, 6024, '192.168.0.26');
client.send('Hello2World!',0, 12, 6024, '192.168.0.26');
client.send('Hello3World!',0, 12, 6024, '192.168.0.26', function(err, bytes) {
client.close();
});
```

(I changed the IP address to the ip address I want to send to instead of the loopback address, and changed the port to 6024 so I can continue using the same wireshark display filter.)

This still exhibits the same behaviour where Wireshark and the other computer cannot detect any messages `server.js` is sending out, but if I send them to my own IP address `192.168.0.25` `client.js` can detect it if run on my computer.

---

I am using `Node.js` version `v16.13.2`

Can anyone point me to a resource that explains how to do this? I've been searching around online for a long time and can only find examples on udp broadcasts and sending to the `127.0.0.1` loopback address. Thanks

Comment: Sending to an IP (this is what you ask in the title) is much much simpler - see linked answer.. Broadcasting is too complex be be used as an example for a simple sending.

Comment: Using that example and swapping out the ip address with `192.168.0.26` makes it stop working (wireshark doesn't detect any packets and the other computer can't receive anything either). I just now realized I forgot to add this into my attempted solutions section so I'll be making an edit now. Sorry for wasting your time